# Why do construction machines cuddle?

Tags: civil-engineering

I've noticed that construction equipment & heavy machinery are often parked closely together, as if they are cuddling.

[image]

What is the purpose of that parking technique?

Comment: Can make it potentially harder to steal.  Its why you sometimes see cargo trucks and trailers parked back to back.  Their doors cannot be swung open until one of the vehicles moves.

Comment: @ForwardEd That's what I initially thought but I don't see how that applies to the vehicles in the photo. Maybe it's not to protect the entire vehicle but the shovel on the front since I think they are swappable.

Comment: Reduce the space needed. Allows other trucks room to move. If they were left all over the yard it would be like  trying to drive around a maze...

Comment: @DKNguyen I think that you are correct about protecting the shovel ... the way it is in the picture, it would be difficult to disconnect the shovel and drag it onto a truck

Comment: I'm with the shovel protection. The shovels are easily detached. In my area machines are often parked up with the excavator how pressing down on the second bucket to prevent theft of either.

Comment: @Transistor I asked a friend of mine who works scaffolding and he said no. They just did that being they were screwing around.

Comment: @jsotola Guess not. See above.

Comment: I figured that it's either to make it harder to steal parts or they were hoping to get a bunch of [mini-loaders](https://www.paddockmachinery.com/products/mini-loader-diesel-skid-steer).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word is huddle. It is standard practice to place heavy equipment close together for security and site safety management.